# VsHub server has stopped working

Tags: windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 Professional. Whenever I `run` or `debug` my project it shows error:

> Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe has stopped working.

It open 100s of popup message of this error.

[image: Popup Message Comes when debug and run project's]

Already tried solution:

- Solution1: Repair and Re-install Visual Studio.

Please! don't suggest for format PC.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different solutions to this problem that I find when searching around so I'll post all in the order I would try:

1. Head over to [Update to improve Diagnostic Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3090034/update-to-improve-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015) and download the <kbd>[`Microsoft Patch`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=f6d2d811-c279-4048-afb2-dc2060b81c88&displaylang=en)</kbd>

   > ### Cause
   >
   > These problems occur because of race conditions in Visual Studio
   >   Diagnostic Tools that may cause the tools to fail during debugging.
   >   The race conditions cause the Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe
   >   process to crash or the Visual Studio instance to stop responding when
   >   you debug.

---

2. As per [How to fix: HttpHostx64.exe has stopped working](https://thomas-barthelemy.github.io/2015/05/01/visual-studio-vshub/) you can give these steps a shot to potentially resolve if the patch in #1 doesn't fix the problem

   > ### The fix
   >
   > It seems that the x86 version of the file does not have the same
   >   issue, so a simple fix, until a better one is officially published by
   >   Microsoft:
   >
   > - Stop Visual Studio if started rename    Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe to
   >     Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe.bak
   > - Create a copy of Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe and rename it    Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHostx64.exe
   > - Re-start Visual Studio
   >
   > The issue has been reported and a thread is available here:
   >
   > https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1293295/httphostx64-exe-has-stopped-working

---

3. Per [MSDN Post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652543.aspx) a workaround is suggested so give it a shot if needed:

   > ### Workaround
   >
   > To work around this issue, uninstall the software that detours network
   >   activity. Or, contact the application vendor for additional support.

---

4. I also noticed that many people suggest that removing Web Companion from [Lavasoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavasoft) and removing all or any registry entries containing [Lavasoft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavasoft) has resolved this for some people.

---

### Further Resources

- [Update to improve Diagnostic Tools in Visual Studio 2015](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3090034/update-to-improve-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015)
- [How to fix: HttpHostx64.exe has stopped working](https://thomas-barthelemy.github.io/2015/05/01/visual-studio-vshub/)
- [How can I fix Visual Studio 2015 exception Microsoft.vshup.server.httphostx64.exe has stopped working when run project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634342/how-can-i-fix-visual-studio-2015-exception-microsoft-vshup-server-httphostx64-ex)

Comment: Be sure to check #3 and #4 on your system and remove any related software that is applicable as that should resolve your issue otherwise if the other steps don't work so please don't overlook those steps if #1 and #2 don't give you the expected results. Be sure to reboot your machine after each change if you test and it does not resolve just to be thorough before applying the next potential fix. I make one change at a time when I do troubleshooting as such.

Comment: Hi, I saw `lavasoft` folder inside `Program files` after uninstalling it, **visual studio** again shows that `error popup`. I am not sure if all registry are clear or not. Do you have any suggestion to clear all registry related to `lavasoft`. Thanks for help!

Comment: Deleting all `lavasoft` registry worked for me. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

An advice was [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35104481/165358) :

1. Position to the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared`
2. Rename the folder `VSHub` to something like `VSHub1`
3. Restart Visual Studio
4. If it works now, delete the renamed folder.